# Android mobile wiping softwares for ubuntu

Tags: android

are there any applications that can be used to wipe away and factory reset an android china tablet i have tried this one but this looks to be made only for windows
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73932943/Unlocking%20Tool.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to do a factory reset? Enable USB debugginh in the android device, and then follow this: [How to factory reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685721/how-can-i-do-factory-reset-using-adb-in-android)

I always use [ClockWorkMod](http://www.droidwiki.de/ClockWorkMod)

Comment: clock work mod which you have included displays its specifications and functions in an other language which i am not able to understand can you explain it to me in english

Comment: when i try to reset my android tablet by pressing pwer and volume +  button it displays the directory in chinese which i am unable to understand can any one help me to get rid of this issue

Comment: Picture please?